# CmdLet works in PowerShell but not in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-ise, powershell-cmdlet

Lately I have been developing PowerShell scripts on a Window 8 machine instead of on a Windows Server 2012R2 which I normally do.

I have encountered two very strange things that never happened on the server.
I know, two questions in one post, but I believe they might be connected.

1. After a while cmdlets just stop producing any output whatsoever, no error messages, no verbose output. It doesn't matter if I run it in the "lower" command part or in the "upper" script editor, and no difference if I run a selected part of the script or the whole thing. If I switch to a "normal" PowerShell the cmdlet works fine.  If I restart PowerShell ISE, the cmdlet start working again, but only for a like 2-5 execution (not at all exact number) after which it stops working again.  Not all cmdlets behave this way, mostly had problems with Storage related cmdlets (Format-Partition, Get-Disk, Get-Volume and so on).
2. After a while cmdlets that used to work fine in the "upper" script part of PowerShell ISE just stops working. The cmdlets still work fine in the "lower" command part of the ISE GUI, but does not work when used in the "upper" script editor, even though they did just a second ago. And it doesn't matter if I run the whole script or just a selected part. And by not working I mean it can't even find the cmdlet (The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet). The cmdlet is available in the Commands Side-Bar where it show up without any problem and I can access help for it.

So any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: I've run into quite a lot of issues debugging step-by-step. Sometimes the ISE cannot stop on a line because I don't know, the parsing of it hangs it or something (you cannot Debug>Stop, you have to restart the ISE). If I have a breakpoint on the line after that one and I run to that line, it works and I can debug after that.

Comment: I have not used the debugging feature in Powershell ISE at all when I encountered these problems.

Comment: Do you have anything to show us that we can reproduce your issue? _Output_ is not very specific and I would like to see some of your output lines. ISE and Console are capable of having different profiles loaded so your situations could easily be different.

Comment: Well, when the CmdLet stops working there is no output whatsoever so nothing to show there, and in the other case when it stops working after a while it is the same output as if you try to run "Jump-Pig -height 4 -count 3" 
`PS C:\> Jump-Pig -height 4 -count 3
Jump-Pig : The term 'Jump-Pig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
+ Jump-Pig -height 4 -count 3
+ ~~~~~~~~
 .... 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: Well that error is _very_ specific. The cmdlet is not present when it is called. Is it declared _before_ it is called? If you don't show us a specific example that _we can reproduce_ there is going to be a lot of back and forth here.

Comment: It works fine up to a point where it just stop working. And again, it works fine in the "lower" command-part of Powershell ISE

Comment: I understand what you mean by it works in the console and not the script pane but that does not make sense since they are tied to the same session. I expect that the code is slightly different. If I am wrong please include code so that we can repeat your findings. Else I am not sure what we can do for you

Comment: It is the same code exactly. And I can't repeat it myself on other computers.  I normally do my scripting on a Windows Server 2012R2 and I have never experienced any of these problems there, it only happens on this Windows 8.1 machine I am on now. Also, remember, it works fine when Powershell ISE is first started.